# Wordpress register_nav_menus not working

Tags: wordpress, menu

in file functions.php:

```
function themeaw_setup() //my theme name themeaw
{
   add_theme_support('menus');
   register_nav_menus(array(
        'header-menu' => 'Header Menu',
        'footer-menu' => 'Footer Menu'
   ));
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'themeaw_setup');
//add_action('init', 'themeaw_setup');
```

i try add action 'after_setup_theme' or 'init' but nothing changed. Menu is not created. What's wrong? Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to put this:

```
function themeaw_setup(){
    register_nav_menus(array(
    'header-menu' => 'Header Menu',
    'footer-menu' => 'Footer Menu'
   ));
}

add_action('init ', 'themeaw_setup');
```

With this you can customize the menu in the theme menu options and to display you can do it with for example in the header.php

```
<?php wp_nav_menu (array('theme_location' => 'header-menu','menu_class' => 'nav'));?>
```